# Error al insertar datos a tabla en ASP.NET Core

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, postman

estoy tratando de ingresar a datos a una bd con asp.net core , mi bd esta en sql server pero al ingresar los parámetros en postman me da error 404 , ¿donde esta el error que cometo en mi código para poder corregirlo?, estoy ingresando los parametros que se declara en mi ruta httpPost en postman

```
[HttpPost("setDSDescarga/{@cod_liquidacion}/{@cod_vendedor}/{@cod_estado}/{@flg_liquidacion_generada}/{@fch_fecha}/{@fch_carga}/{@fch_impresion_liquidacion}/{@fch_descarga}/{@fch_aprobacion}")]
        public ActionResult setDSDescarga()
        {
            string _connStr = "Data Source=localhots;Initial Catalog=bd_local;User ID=local;Password=**********";
            string _query = "INSERT INTO [liquidacion] (cod_liquidacion,cod_vendedor,cod_estado,flg_liquidacion_generada,fch_fecha,fch_carga,fch_impresion_liquidacion,fch_descarga,fch_aprobacion) values (codliquidacion,codvendedor,codestado,flgliquidaciongenerada,fchfecha,fchcarga,fchimpresionliquidacion,fchdescarga,fchaprobacion)";
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connStr))
            {
                using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    comm.Connection = conn;
                    comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    comm.CommandText = _query;
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("codliquidacion", "@cod_liquidacion");
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("codvendedor", "@cod_vendedor");
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("codestado", "@cod_estado");
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("flgliquidaciongenerada", "@flg_liquidacion_generada");
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("fchfecha", "@fch_fecha");
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("fchcarga", "@fch_carga");
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("fchimpresionliquidacion", "@fch_impresion_liquidacion");
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("fchdescarga", "@fch_descarga");
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("fchaprobacion", "@fch_aprobacion");

                        conn.Open();
                        return Ok(comm.ExecuteNonQuery());
                    
                }
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: en el values() debes de poner las variables @cod_liq y asi sucesivamente.

Comment: @Manny por que no puede ser casi igual al de las tabla?

Comment: [Route] Necesitas "crear" la ruta que estás queriendo definir en [HttPost]

Answer (score 0):

Debería ser más o menos así:

```
    [HttpPost("setDSDescarga/{cod_liquidacion}/{cod_vendedor}/{cod_estado}/{flg_liquidacion_generada}/{fch_fecha}/{fch_carga}/{fch_impresion_liquidacion}/{fch_descarga}/{fch_aprobacion}")]
    public ActionResult setDSDescarga(string cod_liquidacion, string cod_vendedor, string cod_estado, bool flg_liquidacion_generada, DateTime fch_fecha, DateTime fch_carga, DateTime fch_impresion_liquidacion, DateTime fch_descarga, DateTime fch_aprobacion)
    {
        string _connStr = "Data Source=localhots;Initial Catalog=bd_local;User ID=local;Password=**********";
        string _query = "INSERT INTO [liquidacion] (cod_liquidacion,cod_vendedor,cod_estado,flg_liquidacion_generada,fch_fecha,fch_carga,fch_impresion_liquidacion,fch_descarga,fch_aprobacion) values (@codliquidacion, @codvendedor, @codestado, @flgliquidaciongenerada, @fchfecha, @fchcarga, @fchimpresionliquidacion, @fchdescarga, @fchaprobacion)";
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connStr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand())
            {
                comm.Connection = conn;
                comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                comm.CommandText = _query;
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codliquidacion", cod_liquidacion);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codvendedor", cod_vendedor);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codestado", cod_estado);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@flgliquidaciongenerada", flg_liquidacion_generada);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fchfecha", fch_fecha);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fchcarga", fch_carga);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fchimpresionliquidacion", fch_impresion_liquidacion);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fchdescarga", fch_descarga);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fchaprobacion", fch_aprobacion);
                conn.Open();
                return Ok(comm.ExecuteNonQuery());
            }
        }
    }
```

El caracter `@` se usa para nombrar los parámetros en SQL Server, no debes usarlos en la plantilla de ruta (argumento que le pasas a `HttpPost`) como estabas haciendo.

Luego tienes que declarar los argumentos del método `setDSDescarga` que se enlazan con los que aparecen en la plantilla de ruta y tienen que tener el mismo nombre.

En la instrucción SQL `INSERT` lo que viene en la lista `VALUES` son los parámetros por eso tienes que ponerles la `@` delante.

Y en `AddWithValues` el primer argumento es el nombre del parámetro que estás usando en los `VALUES` y el segundo argumento es el valor del parámetro que lo tomas de los argumentos del método `setDSDescarga`

Dicho esto tengo que recomendarte varias cosas:

- Usa un objeto que tenga las propiedades CodLiquidacion, CodVendedor, etc correspondientes a las columnas de la tabla, en vez de usar una lista interminable de argumentos en el método.
- Añade una capa de acceso a datos y llámala desde el controlador, es muy mala prática tener código de acceso a datos en el controlador.
- No uses `AddWithValue` ya que tiene la mala costumbre de declarar todos los parámetros de tipo cadena como `nvarchar(4000)` y eso a veces produce ineficiencias. Tampoco es bueno para tipos `decimal`